# Html decode to text view

Tags: android

I have a problem with header in text view. I use: `title.setText(Html.fromHtml(headerId));` to convert text to textview from html. Everything is ok but when I have  or other header in html I get a html but with some space from margin. When I do some like this:  `title.setText(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(headerId).toString));` and build version and after that I rturned to old version, my header is in correct place on right side without any space. 
This is how it look:
[image]

and this is how it should looks:
[image]

as you can see Cola Bare is aligned to right but when I start first time that header is not aligned. How I can do that to work from first run?

Edit That looks code from headerId:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with some code?

Comment: I can't give all class code. Only what I can give that "title" is textView and "headerId" is string.

Comment: it looks like your text <h2> text starts from the next line. Any space  more than one will be considered as a space thus showing you that extra space before your header. Try to edit your html file manually, remove the line from the <h2> tag and check how it works

Comment: I think the same, but I get that string from webservice and I can't change that on webservice. This is any way to change it in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that problem by :`replaceAll("^<h1>\\s*","<h1>").replaceAll("^<h2>\\s*","<h2>").replaceAll("^<h3>\\s*","<h3>")`